# What does this 'cr' stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

I saw this chart ([here](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Health_insurance)) and can't figure out what this 'cr' (next to the 9%) means in this context.

[image]

Comment: Cr essentially means 'crore' here. I don't know if Americans and people belonging to other parts of the world use this, it is fairly common in India. I believe you are not Indian, hence you got confused. This would be the full-form because all other full forms of 'cr' or 'CR' do not make sense here. 1 crore = 10 million.

Comment: The chart shouldn't be held up as "credible" use of English, in terms of either syntax *or* vocabulary (in "real" English it would be *90 million Indians **are** expected to be diabetic by 2025*).

Comment: As @DhanishthaGhosh suggests this is an India usage as is the _lakh_ 1 _crore_ = 100 _lakh_.

Comment: This image was taken from here: https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Health_insurance. It didn't look like an Indian site but general.

Comment: @JudiciousAllure - The caption on the picture at the site you're linking says, "Advertising the need for health insurance in India."  So while the site might not be Indian, the diagram itself is clearly identified as Indian.

Answer (score 3):

“cr” appears to represent crore.
10,000,000 in Indian numbering.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore